# Table of Contents Heading 1 wide spacing

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using MS-word 2016. I was trying to find a solution to hiding the number beside a heading 1 in word e.g. instead of `1. CHAPTER ONE: INTRODUCTION`, i'd have just `CHAPTER ONE: INTRODUCTION`, whereas all the other types of headings would have numberings e.g. `1.1 Background` and in Chapter two, they start as `2.1 Existing Systems` etc. So I stumbled upon a solution which stated that one can press `Ctrl+Shift+H` to hide the numbers for heading 1 and it works very okay.

Now my issue is that when I generate the Table of Contents, the headings level 1 have very wide spaces between them. Like they are forced to fit the size of the page. However, they are okay in the document itself. Please check the images I have placed [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZeV3ruXUyVVseLevPwdbDpDshAoRvymS). I apologize, but I am not able to embed images here since I have below 10 reputation points. As soon as I get them I'll post them here.

I have tried right and left alignments but the headings are placed on the right side with their page numbers going below them. I am sure this is caused by hiding the headings 1 numbering. I also don't know how to unhide the numbers. My question requires the following key solutions: solving this issue on the table of contents or using another way to hide heading 1 numbering instead of Ctrl+Shift+H and unhiding the numbers

**EDIT**

After upvotes to my question (which I am very grateful for), I am able to post the images here. 
So at first my chapters were numbered as shown here: [image: this sample image.]

This is how my original table of contents was: [image: here.]

I wanted to remove the numberings on the chapters only, but retain those on the other subheadings level 2 and 3. I read somewhere (don't have the link at the moment), that I could use the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+H` which actually works as shown here:[image: in this sample chapter image].

The problem is, when I update the old table of contents or even generate a new one, it appears with the headings widely spaced as shown: [image: here].

I have tried to forcefully left or right align the chapter names inside the table of contents and in both cases this is the result: [image: as shown in this image]

I am requesting if someone can help me to achieve the hiding of the numbers but without messing up table of contents or if there is a way to correct the table of contents as it is at the moment without manually doing it i.e. typing them on the table of contents to make them look okay (this gets overwritten when table is updated).

Comment: upload your images to http://imgur.com and link to them. Someone with enough reputation will likely embed them for you.

Comment: Maybe I’m just not focusing clearly enough, but I don’t understand what you’re showing us in those pictures.  For example, is the second one any more than a continuation of the first one?  Ditto for the fourth and the fifth.  Please explain more. … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the settings for Heading 1 in the TOC? It looks like you're trying to manually change things and that is never a good idea in Word.